# C# Chart date type x axis is not hiding empty point

Tags: c#, charts, is-empty

Basically my C# chart control has a `datetime` type x axis.

I am plotting 2 different time period, but do not want the empty points to even show up in the x axis.

Is it possible to change a certain property of the chart control to hide the period of time which does not have point.

[image]

Comment: I have an image link for this question
http://tinypic.com/r/6e2c83/5

Comment: I had to change the x axis to string type for the time being. I am still looking forward to a solution to this.

Comment: if youdon't want the x-axis to be scaled to the x-values simply set the/all series to be indexed: chart1.Series[0].IsXValueIndexed

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar to your problem, here is what I used (C#), it may help:

```
Chart4.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalType.Number, Chart4.Series["s3"]);
                Chart4.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalType.Number, Chart4.Series["s2"]);
                Chart4.Series["s3"].EmptyPointStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                Chart4.Series["s2"].EmptyPointStyle.Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
```

You can specify the intervalType.Days in place of number..

Answer (score 0):

```
datamanipulator.ignoreemptypoints = true;
```

from this article on grouping:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489213.aspx

Comment: Hi This did not workout for me. It ignore empty points by default

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the x-axis to be scaled to the x-values simply set the/all series to be **indexed**:

```
foreach (Series s in chart1.Series) s.IsXValueIndexed = true;
```

Now each `DataPoint` will sit at its **index position** instead of its **x-value position**. **Note** that this also mean that you need to make sure **all** `Series` **aligned**, read all have a `DataPoint` at the same indices, be it a real one or an `Empty` one or else the will shift..!